# 1953 Marum Cycle Company 15" Interested in any info and importance of this bike

Tags: vintage

Why can't I find this bicycle or anything on the company that makes it? The tube cover says Special'53. It has rod brakes, leather spring seat and KING HOMERUN TYRES that have fossilized to the rims.  Seat tube measures 15"  The tubes were still partially wrapped with brown paper. . I want to sell it but I have no idea where it's from.  Any info would be a great help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found [this](https://tr.letgo.com/en/i/collector-bike-only-one-around_9ec671b9-f80b-44a6-97ba-49b25094ba7c).  The guy says it's from the Netherlands.  His is in *much* worse condition and he's asking $1000, so chances are yours is actually worth something.

Comment: I suggest checking with the folks at the Classic and Antique Bicycle Exchange (theCABE.com). They are likely to know the brand and value. Post a lot of photos. You might even find a buyer there.

Comment: As with everything, it's only worth what someone is willing to pay for it. While we're on the subject I thought valuations and what's my bike worth were off topic?

Comment: Props to D.R.Hicks and Andrew for going above and beyond and taking the time and effort to help answer my questions.   Thanks so much!   You guys are a real asset to this website!

Comment: Does the tyre have letters for tread ?   Its certainly 1970s at the latest because of cotter cranks.  But rod brakes are a truely ancient design, going away in the 40s or so.   The training wheels look newer and homemade, and have replaced the kickstand (which is pictured backwards btw.)   Loverly bike, quite small.

Comment: @DanK you're right, actual valuations are off topic - the link is to some more information that happens to have an asking price for that one.